# Java error when combined with screen command in ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, gnu-screen

I am running a Linux 2.6.38-10-server #46-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux and I have the following problem:

1) I log in ssh

2) I start a screen (using the screen command)

3) I start a java program " java -jar ../mlJar.jar > eval1" and pipe the output to eval1

4) I detach the screen (Ctrl+A, Crtl+D)

5) The program will run correctly unless I log-off

6) After logging off and when the java app tries to open a file it throws the following exception

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /path/to/my/file.arff (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
        at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:41)
        at gr.auth.ee.lcs.utilities.InstancesUtility.openInstance(InstancesUtility.java:74)
        at gr.auth.ee.lcs.data.representations.complex.ComplexRepresentation.<init>(ComplexRepresentation.java:834)
        at gr.auth.ee.lcs.data.representations.complex.StrictMultiLabelRepresentation.<init>(StrictMultiLabelRepresentation.java:456)
        at gr.auth.ee.lcs.implementations.SequentialUCS.<init>(SequentialUCS.java:165)
        at gr.auth.ee.lcs.implementations.SequentialUCS.createNew(SequentialUCS.java:196)
        at gr.auth.ee.lcs.FoldEvaluator.evaluate(FoldEvaluator.java:153)
        at gr.auth.ee.lcs.implementations.global.AllMlTypes.main(AllMlTypes.java:69)
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at gr.auth.ee.lcs.FoldEvaluator.loadFold(FoldEvaluator.java:211)
        at gr.auth.ee.lcs.FoldEvaluator.evaluate(FoldEvaluator.java:155)
        at gr.auth.ee.lcs.implementations.global.AllMlTypes.main(AllMlTypes.java:69)`

Which probably means that this happens because the JVM has "lost" it's access rights to the folder.

Can anyone help with how to solve the problem. In other versions of linux this doesn't happen. Is there any configuration in Linux that can sort this out?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you certain this is happening after you log out?  This message looks like it breaks when you want to run the java-jar command.

Comment: Agreed. There's nothing about opening a file in that stack trace. Maybe the exception is happening, and you're just not seeing it until you log back in?

Comment: Actually you are right. This error happens after I try to give again the same command. The problem is the same. I will correct the question in a moment. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that your home directory might be encrypted (using `ecryptfs`) and might be getting unmounted when you log off.

There is a bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+bug/525562

I believe the auto-unmounting can be stopped by removing `~/.ecryptfs/auto-unmount`

Comment: That's it! I moved all files out of the home directory and everything is fixed! Thanks!